# Allen Coggan power profile table for Cyclo cross riders?

Tags: cyclocross, power

If you were to create a power profile based on those seen in training and racing with a power meter by Hunter Allen and Andrew Coggan. What would it look like a sprinter or an all rounder?

To help answer the question I have found an article which lists some of the power put out in certain zones by Ryan Trebon during a cyclo cross nationals race.

Rider weight: 80kgs

estimated ftp is: 415 watts or 5.19 w/kg (rounded up by .25, not sure if that's the right thing to do?)

Max power is: 1431 watts

The article goes on to state that he produces 'between 400w and 800w, or between about 95 and 190% of his FTP. He accelerated more than 120 times at or near 850w for 20 to 30 seconds (10.6w/kg). 120 times!'. To top it all off 'He goes on to produce 11 more maximal sprints at 1200+w throughout the race, ending with a final maximal kick within the final 500m of 1190w'.

Link to the article: http://www.cxmagazine.com/training-cyclocross-power-ryan-trebon-wattage-file

Comment: Closer to an all-rounder but there's a slight difference depending on the type of cyclocross you race on. Generally speaking, European cyclocross runs are a little longer, North American cyclocross runs are a shorter and steeper. Also, it appears Coggan is de-emphasizing power profiles and is switching to FRC profiles.

Comment: I like this article

Answer (score 1):

That's some wattage, but lower than Coggan's charts for an international pro road racer (5.78w/kg+ for FTP), I guess due to:

- the fact that this is race data and not best efforts from testing/training;
- and because perhaps it's less important for cyclo-cross riders as they don't tend to do as long climbs as you might expect in a Grand Tour.

Yeah, I agree with the comment above: probably closer to an All-Rounder; maybe a hint of Pursuiter in there too. Would need data for 5s, 1min and 5min maximum best efforts.

Comment: The book training and racing with a power meter 'Power meter files from CX races typically show and average of 20 to 40 watts below what the actual ftp of the athlete is' It then goes on to list reasons why this is which include 'the down time of a CX race, running and tight corners' and the lack of traction. The ability to put the power to the ground skews the power down, and one has to take this into consideration when reviewing cx files.

I have guestimated his power profile from your hint of a pursuit rider suggestion:

5 secs: 17.79 w/kg
1 min: 10.70 w/kg
5 min: 6.46 w/kg
ftp:   5.15 w/kg

Answer (score 0):

If you look at former cyclocrossers who have moved into the pro peloton (Lars Boom, Zdenek Stybar come to mind), many of them end up specializing in the Spring Classics (Paris-Roubaix, etc).  In the multi-day tours, they are all-rounders, capable of winning stages, though not usually near the top of the GC.